# Setting custom permissions within a "dashboard" area in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm putting together a side project for a teacher/student type of website where the student will share a dashboard with the teacher. The teacher and student can both upload files and leave comments in the dashboard.

The part that I'm stuck on is the permission. For student, I've set up the index controller to this method

```
def index
@Homework = Homework.where(:user_id = current_user) 
end
```

With this, I'm able to have the student only see the work that they have, but I'm confused on how to get the teacher to see each individual student's work?

Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Do you have any relationships between teachers and students? i.e. to teachers ```have_many``` students and students ```belong_to``` teachers? Do either have any relationships to homework?  Are they all 'users' with different type attributes?

If you can give us some more on how you have your data modeled, we can help you much more effectively.

Comment: a teacher has_many students and a student belongs to a teacher. student and teachers has_many homework.

Comment: @JustinD. Cancan is great, but the thing I'm confused about is how to set the controller view right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution if you only ever need to support **a single class** in your application:

```
def index
  if current_user.teacher?
    @homeworks = Homework.all
  else 
    @homeworks = Homework.where(user_id: current_user)
  end
end
```

Otherwise, your Homework schema does not seem to be correctly designed. See your query below:

```
Homework.where(:user_id = <student_id>)
```

This works to retrieve a student's homeworks, but it does not work to retrieve a teacher's students' homeworks. You may need a class_id for a teacher to see each individual student's work:

```
Homework.where(:class_id = <class_id>, :user_id = <student_id>)
```

A Class has_many Teachers and has_many Students. This design will allow you to support multiple classes.

Some more guiding questions:

- Is teacher/student both kept in the same User model?
- How do you differentiate between teacher/student in your current User model?
- Is there a "user_type" column somewhere in User?
- What happens if the current_user is of the "teacher" user_type?

For complex user permissions, use CanCanCan: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 0):

Don't use uppercase instance variables. ex: @Homework should be @homework

Check out the gem CanCan. Install it (follow the instructions, you should have to put something in application controller), Then, put in your ability file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, Homework, user_id: user.id
  end
end
```

Then at the top of your StudentController put

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

And the index action should look like:

```
@homework = @student.homework
```

Now, you didn't post your whole controller so this is a much as I can help.

I believe you may have a bigger underlying issue. You have students and teachers has_many homework i read in your comment. Then in your example you use user_id. You are likely overriding your students and teacher ownership of homework. You would need a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship OR you would need a student_id and teacher_id columns on the homework table

Cancan automatically generate a number of instance variables which can make it feel like magic. Watch the free railscasts on cancan the same guy who made the video wrote the CanCan library.